# How can I get the number of bytes read in an asynchronous read?

Tags: .net, asynchronous

Using C#, how can I return the number of bytes read from the function where I call EndRead?

ie:

```
x.BeginRead (...ReadProc..);
// how can I get the number of bytes read here?

ReadProc (IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int numBytesRead = EndRead ();
    // how can I return numBytesRead?

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really want to use the Async code?  With asynchronous calls there is no way to know how many bytes were read until the async call is done which will be in a different thread of execution.

You can block after calling BeginRead and use a mutex of some sort to wait until the EndRead is done and then get the value, but then there's no point in doing it asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it back where you called BeginRead, you are missing a trick; you might as well just call Read. The whole point of async is that you typically process the data in a disconnected way.

However, you can also call EndRead in the originating method if all you want to do is so *something else* while it is reading. Just don't specify a callback.